# How to show data pulled from .json in a gridview?

Tags: c#, json, gridview, windows-phone-8.1

I need help for something relatively simple, but I can't find any solution:
I am using JSON.NET to pull data from here: https://yts.to/api/ , and am looking for a way to place each movie in a gridview, with a picturebox showing the poster, and the title and year underneath, like this app concept I did: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5YUk.jpg

Other than that, I have finished about half the app, but I'm rather new to C# and XAML, so if I could possibly have code, that would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to use `listbox` rather then `GridView`. You can style your `listbox` using `ItemTemplate`. Below is an example for you

```
<ListBox Name="lstView" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
             <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}"></Image>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Binding from `C#`:

```
public class Article
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
}


 Article article1 = new Article() { Name = "name1", ImagePath = "path of image 1" };
 Article article2 = new Article() { Name = "name2", ImagePath = "path of image 2" };

 var articles = new List<Article>();
 articles.Add(article1);
 articles.Add(article2);

 lstView.DataContext = articles;
```

You need to work on conversion part from JSON to Object.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! So now I have this: http://i.imgur.com/ULVmVAV.png , but how do I get it to be a grid, and not a list? :/